# Detect bad link referrer neighborhood using CURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to use CURL to assess the visitors on my site. I'd like to see if they are being linked from a bad neighborhood or not. Most of the time my current code works, but not always.

I'm having a bit of trouble making my CURL able to fool all servers. How do I make my CURL headers totally convincing, and remove any possible clues that I'm using CURL?

```
<?php 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$vars);  //Post Fields
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'X-Apple-Tz: 0';
$headers[] = 'X-Apple-Store-Front: 143444,12';
$headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5';
$headers[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8';
$headers[] = 'Host: www.example.com';
$headers[] = 'Referer: http://www.example.com/index.php'; //Your referrer address
$headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0';
$headers[] = 'X-MicrosoftAjax: Delta=true';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

print $server_output;

curl_close ($ch);    

if (strpos($output,'sex') !== false) 
{
    echo 'sex';
}

?>
```

For example, a certain well known adult video site with an orange logo that looks a lot like the YouTube logo (maybe you guys know the one) responded with this:

```
403 Forbidden

Request forbidden by administrative rules. 
__SERVERNAME__
```

Comment: use a browser debugger and capture ALL of the headers they send, including cookies. once you replicate that in curl, there shouldn't be any way to identify it's curl just from the one request.

Comment: I'm really not an expert in browser debuggers - could you help me get this right?

Comment: on firefox, get httpfox. it lets you inspect all headers.

Comment: Oh wow, I just got a similar one for chrome - this will really help with debugging as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In chrome dev tools, you can obtain the full HTTP request chrome used against a URL by:

- opening dev tools
- goto the "network" tab
- request the URL you want - if you are already on the target page - hit F5 or reload.
  Dev tools will then generate a list of HTTP requests (and responses) made
- right click on the HTTP request / URL you are interested in
- click the "save as curl" option and you will now have the full HTTP request details (for command line curl ) in your clipboard.

By using these values when sending an HTTP request your request will ostensibly appear to be made by a Chrome web browser.

Comment: Ok, I changed the headers as you suggested. But it still appears I'm getting caught: 403 Forbidden

Request forbidden by administrative rules. 
__SERVERNAME__

Comment: Yes its a quite simplistic approach and not guaranteed to work. But did you try directly  pasting and running the command from command line using command line curl?

Comment: No, where do I do that? :)

Comment: I just tested the command against -  what I think is the site you described -and it worked for me. It may be possible your IP address is being blocked due to your previous attempts.

Comment: you need to have command line curl installed. if you do then simply paste the curl command dev tools put into your clipboard and hit "enter". You will likely see a huge long command, these are all the header including cookies etc chrome inserts into its requests

Comment: Thanks for all the info. I'll accept the answer, as this site has probably the most zealous developer team after google. It's me that's tripping some piece of fishing wire they've laid out for me somewhere.

Comment: cool, out of interest what actually were you trying to determine? I couldn't make what you would find out by making curl requests to the site - in which case it may be better to re-ask the question along those lines?

Comment: I'm looking for certain common keywords that determine the nature of the website that traffic is coming from such as "sex, blog, forum, chat"